# Asp .net Form generate alert on closing/leaving form, if user made changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to create a form, that ask me from an alert if I want to leave without saving the changes I am using JavaScript for validation and have tried some code to do this but can't get any message/alert while leaving page.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         var chk = new Array();
         window.onload = assign;
         function assign() {
             chk[0] = '<%=TextBox1.Text%>';
             chk[1] = '<%=TextBox2.Text%>';
             chk[2] = '<%=TextBox3.Text%>';
         }
         window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
         function confirmExit() {
             if (chk[0] != '<%=TextBox1.Text%>'||chk[1] != '<%=TextBox2.Text%>'||chk[2] != '<%=TextBox3.Text%>')
             return "Do you want to leave page without save changes ?";
         }

    </script>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Id"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">zeejay</asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">zee</asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server">zeejay@hotmail.com</asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your if condition always false that's why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These server-side tags `<%=TextBox3.Text%>` will only be evaluated once (before the is page rendered on the client), therefore your JavaScript expression will never return true.

Here is a simpler way:

Leverage the "on" function to attach an event handler to any change, keyup, or keydown events for any inputs, textareas, or selects

```
$('#body-content').on('change keyup keydown', 'input, textarea, select', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('changed-input');
});
```

Attach to the "beforeunload" event and check if the form is dirty by seeing if any elements with a class of "changed-input" exist.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    if ($('.changed-input').length) {
        return 'You haven\'t saved your changes.';
    }
});
```

Source: 
http://www.bitnative.com/2013/08/19/warn-users-of-unsaved-changes-with-jquery/

Comment: Thank you so much for replying me this is very new thing for me because I am a beginner in JavaScript. Your code is working perfectly on buttons but cant show any alert on making changes in textboxes, if I leave the page.

Comment: What does your script section look like now?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    if (canExit) return null; // null will allow exit without a question
    // Else, just return the message you want to display
    return "Do you really want to close?";
});
```

Comment: A short description in the answer would clarify what you mean.